# Calculating the fourier series of $f(t)=|t|$

Tags: fourier-series

calculate the Fourier series of the $2\pi$-periodic continuation of

$$f(t):=|t|, \quad t\in[-\pi,\pi)\tag{1}$$

We know that

$$f(t)=\sum_{k=-N}^N c_k\cdot e^{ikt}\quad \&\quad c_k=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)e^{-ikt}dt\tag{2}$$

So let's calcualte the $c_k$.

$$c_k=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-pi}^\pi|t|\cdot e^{-ikt}dt=\frac{2}{2\pi}\int_0^\pi t\cdot \cos(tk) dt=\frac{1}{\pi}[t\cdot\sin(tk)]_0^\pi+\frac{1}{\pi}[\cos(tk)]_0^\pi=0\frac{1}{\pi}(-1-1)=\frac{-2}{\pi}\tag{3}$$

Whereas we used the identity $\int_{-a}^a|t|e^{-ikt}dt=2\int_0^a t\cos(kt)dt$ [Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJDt8.jpg) (wheres the sub $t\to -t$ was used in the 2nd step)

So we get

$$f(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{-2}{\pi}e^{ikt}\tag{4}$$

Sadly I don't have any solutions. Is that correct?

Comment: You can never have a nonzero value independent of $k$ for $c_k$, by Riemann Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: Yeah of course, that's a stupid mistake.  But do you see any other issue here?

Comment: You will have to calculate $c_0$ seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integration is incorrect. Note that the anti-derivative of $\cos(kt)$ is $\frac{\sin(kt)}{k}$, so we have

\begin{align} 
\int t\cos(kt) dt &= t \color{red}{\frac{\sin(kt)}{k}} - \int\frac{\sin(kt)}{k}dt \\
&= t\color{red}{\frac{\sin(kt)}{k}} + \color{red}{\frac{\cos(kt)}{k^2}}
\end{align}

Inserting the limits gives

$$ c_k = \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\cos(k\pi)-1}{k^2} = \begin{cases} 0, && k \text{ even} \\ \dfrac{-2}{\pi k^2}, && k \text{ odd} \end{cases} $$

Comment: Yeah, that was a stupid mistake. Thanks

Comment: There is a small mistake. $c_0$ is not $0$.

Comment: @xotix Don't forget $c_0$!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I didn't say $c_0$ was $0$. Thanks for reminding us though!

Comment: @Dylan I am a bit confused to the borders of the sum. if I have $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ it's clear that I have to calculate $c_0$ but when do I have $\sum_{k=-N}^N$ and when do I have $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ and when do I have $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty$?

Comment: Fourier series generally have $k$ go to $\infty$. If it's a real-valued series (with $\sin$ and $\cos$ instead) then you'd have $k \ge 0$. For both versions you have to compute $c_0$

Comment: I have $\sum_{k=-N}^N c_k e^{ikt}$ and $\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^N a_k\cos(kt)+b_k\sin(kt)$ no? For $N \to \infty$ I get the fourier series, no? So I'd actually have to split the first sum to $c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k e^{ikt} + \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1} c_k e^{ikt}$?

Comment: Yes, the constant term is "hidden" in there. But $c_k$ should be the same expression for all $k\ne 0$

Answer (score 1):

The right side of 2nd step of your [substitution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJDt8.jpg) might be better expanded, assuming $a \ge 0$, as

$
\int_{-a}^0 |t| (\cos(st) + i \sin(st)) \ dt \\
= \int_{-a}^0 (-t) (\cos(st) + i \sin(st)) \ dt \ [ \ \because |t| = -t, t \le 0 \ ] \\
= \int_0^a t (\cos(-st) + i \sin(-st)) \ dt \ [ \ \text{substituting} \  t \to -t \ ] \\
= \int_0^a t (\cos(st) - i \sin(st)) \ dt
$

Comment: Yeah I didn't really like that they continues with $|t|$ but I though Im not going to change it. Thanks